# Ruby RSpec "no such file to load" Error

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I'm struggeling with RSpec, I just can't get RSpec to work in my Ruby project. Not even in the easy example provided in the "Get Started Now" section of the official homepage of RSpec: http://rspec.info/

So I take the code from the official example and create bowling.rb and bowling_spec.rb. When i try to run rspec from the console with:

```
rspec bowling_spec.rb --format nested
```

I get this output:

```
require': no such file to load -- bowling (LoadError)
from C:/.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from C:/.../bowling_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load'
from C:/.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `block in load_spec_files'
from C:/.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `map'
from C:/.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load_spec_files'
from C:/.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
from C:/.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
from C:/.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from C:/.../Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:11:in `block in autorun'
```

I tried to run RSpec on my own project with Netbans 7.0.1 as well as with Aptanda Studio 3. I always get this same error. The gem list show the following rspec gems:

- rspec (2.6.0)
- rspec-core (2.6.4)
- rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
- rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
- rspec-rails (2.6.1)
- rspec-rails-controller (0.1.2)

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Solved it when working with the command line. You have to put the bowling_spec.rb in spec/bowling_spec.rb and the bowling.rb in lib/bowling.rb for it to work. For Netbeans and Aptana i still get the same error though.

Comment: Are you using `require 'bowling'` (or `require 'bowling.rb'`) to load the file? If so, you might want to use `require './path/to/bowling.rb'` or add your `lib` directory to your load path.

Comment: You should rarely need to require a .rb directly.  And if you do, you should probably know why you're doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution for getting it to work in Netbeans too is to maunally install Rspec, since Netbeans doesn't have RSpec Version 2 support:

```
gem install rspec -v 1.3.2
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I had this problem, too, and the issue was that I had accidentally `require`'ed `spec_helper.rb` in a non-spec class in a gem.  *That* was fun to find.